# SQL and MS-Access: Matching one:many, match just first observation of group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a dataset of 800k unique customers, and then about 3.5 million customer orders. In the customer orders table I have data such as Zip code, etc. These details changed between orders (if a customer moved for example), so right now I need to match the unique customers with the FIRST details.

So in customers I have (for example) (custID is primary key, no duplications)

`CustID    | First Year Ordered   | Last Year Ordered 
  001        1995                   2005
  002        1996                   2004
  003        1995                   2011
  ...        ...                    ...`

And in customer Orders I have:

`CustID    | Year      | Address                  | DOB
 001         1995        123 Fake Street            01/01/1970
 001         1996        456 Other Street           NULL
 ...          ...           ...                       ...
 002         1996        201 East West St           02/02/1965
 ...          ...           ...                       ...`

Each customer ID in has between 1-50 orders, and I want the info relating ONLY to the first order, so that the final output is:

`CustID       |    First Year  |  Last Year|  Address           | DOB
 001                1995            2005      123 Fake Street     01/01/1990
 002                1996            2004      201 East West ST    02/02/1965
 ...                ...             ...       ...                 ...`

Does anyone know how to do that? Since I'm in access, i thought I could use the First() command (having sorted the table previously by year), but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In the customer orders table, can you have more than one record per CustID in the same year?

Comment: Well, I'm in the process of building the year into a date format using the "quarter" field to indicate the month, so pretty soon I'll have one record per year/month combo

Answer (score 1):

I was silly and wasn't thinking. I created unique year/month identifiers and then joined the table on those and selected accordingly. This way I was choosing which details observation to select by matching them on the right year. Thanks!